# Finding multiple MongoDB results containing similar nested objects

Tags: mongodb

I have some users with multiple social networking accounts attached to them. Somewhere along the line some users have been able to create multiple accounts with these same networks, and I'm trying to get them all remerged.

I have a structure kind of like this:

```
users: [
  {
     accounts: [
       {
         type: "twitter", uid: 123123
       },
       {
         type: "facebook", uid: 123123
       }
     ]
   }
]
```

I have multiple users with the same twitter account for instance, and I want to return them all. I use a query like

```
 db.users.find({"accounts.type": "twitter", "accounts.uid" : 123123});
```

and no matter what I only get back one result though I am 100% sure more than use contains this ID. I've also tried

```
db.users.find({"accounts: {"type": "twitter", "uid": 123123}});
```

What could I be missing here? It's causing some strange problems so I'd like to get this wrapped up quickly, thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I believe it is only giving back the results with *only* that account, not results with multiple.

Comment: Is users embedded collection or it's root?

Answer (score 2):

Your query is just fine, try it in shell :

```
db.users.save({accounts: [{type: "twitter", uid: 12345},{type: "facebook", uid: 67890}]})
db.users.save({accounts: [{type: "twitter", uid: 12345},{type: "facebook", uid: 67890}]})
db.users.count({'accounts.type':"twitter", 'accounts.uid':12345})
2
```

Post two full sample documents and your queries as they appear in the mongo log (setProfilingLevel(2)) if your problem persists after verifying.

Also, just for the sake of completeness, you can try :

```
db.users.count({accounts:{$elemMatch:{type: "twitter", uid: 12345}}})
```

Which does exactly the same but is slightly more "correct"

Comment: I did exactly this but I would only get a result if it contained *only* twitter uid 12345, if it also have a facebook acct it wouldn't work. Could it have something to do with my mongo version?

Comment: Well that's exactly the scenario i'm testing in my example so it should work. What version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it work using something like this:

```
db.users.find({"$where": "function(){for(var i in this.accounts){if(this.accounts[i].type='twitter'&&this.accounts[i].uid==123123){return true;}}}"});
```

Seems kind of like too much for what I'm trying to do though - if anyone has a better solution let me know!

Comment: This is not needed for this usecase. On top of that $where queries are considerably slower than their native counterparts.

Comment: I realize the speed implications but at this point it is all that has been working

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should be using $elemMatch because you have several types of accounts for every user. Then it should work properly.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29

Read the section "Matching with $elemMatch". It is explained there better than I would be able to.